# Automating setup of the SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, password, ssh-tunneling, expect

I need to frequently login to many machines but I can only login to them from a proxy machine or using an SSH tunnel (by tunneling through that proxy machine). The problem is that I cannot use `authorized_keys` on the proxy machine, therefore I need to enter the password every time I setup the tunnel.

How can I automate it? I was thinking about combining `expect` with some way to enter the password automatically without having to store it openly.

I am using Linux on all of the machines mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

How about using agent forwarding?

You can enable it in /etc/ssh/ssh_config (or ~/.ssh/config):

```
Host *
ForwardAgent yes
```

or add "-A" every time you connect to your proxy: `ssh -A user@remote_host`

By enabling this, you allow your proxy to forward your key to your target machines, so you can freely connect to other machines.